# linking with c binding of library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, static, linker

I'm trying to link with the next library:([see docs](http://code.google.com/p/uchardet/))

It's a `C` binding for a lib written in `C++`. But if make static lib and then try to link to it.

I get these messages:

```
uchardet//libuchardet.a(uchardet.cpp.o): In function `uchardet_new':
uchardet.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
uchardet.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
uchardet.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)'
uchardet.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(uchardet.cpp.o): In function `HandleUniversalDetector::Reset()':
uchardet.cpp:(.text._ZN23HandleUniversalDetector5ResetEv[_ZN23HandleUniversalDetector5ResetEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(uchardet.cpp.o): In function `HandleUniversalDetector::Report(char const*)':
uchardet.cpp:(.text._ZN23HandleUniversalDetector6ReportEPKc[_ZN23HandleUniversalDetector6ReportEPKc]+0x35): undefined reference to `std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(uchardet.cpp.o): In function `HandleUniversalDetector::~HandleUniversalDetector()':
uchardet.cpp:(.text._ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD2Ev[_ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD5Ev]+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
uchardet.cpp:(.text._ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD2Ev[_ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD5Ev]+0x4d): undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(uchardet.cpp.o): In function `HandleUniversalDetector::~HandleUniversalDetector()':
uchardet.cpp:(.text._ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD0Ev[_ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD0Ev]+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
uchardet.cpp:(.text._ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD0Ev[_ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD0Ev]+0x2c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet.cpp:(.text._ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD0Ev[_ZN23HandleUniversalDetectorD0Ev]+0x55): undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(uchardet.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI23HandleUniversalDetector[_ZTI23HandleUniversalDetector]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(uchardet.cpp.o):(.eh_frame+0xab): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o): In function `nsUniversalDetector::HandleData(char const*, unsigned int)':
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x396): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x3c6): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x4eb): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x527): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x53a): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x554): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o): In function `nsUniversalDetector::~nsUniversalDetector()':
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text+0x5bc): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o): In function `nsCharSetProber::~nsCharSetProber()':
nsUniversalDetector.cpp:(.text._ZN15nsCharSetProberD0Ev[_ZN15nsCharSetProberD0Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI19nsUniversalDetector[_ZTI19nsUniversalDetector]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV19nsUniversalDetector[_ZTV19nsUniversalDetector]+0x30): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV15nsCharSetProber[_ZTV15nsCharSetProber]+0x20): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV15nsCharSetProber[_ZTV15nsCharSetProber]+0x28): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV15nsCharSetProber[_ZTV15nsCharSetProber]+0x30): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV15nsCharSetProber[_ZTV15nsCharSetProber]+0x38): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV15nsCharSetProber[_ZTV15nsCharSetProber]+0x40): more undefined references to `__cxa_pure_virtual' follow
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI15nsCharSetProber[_ZTI15nsCharSetProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUniversalDetector.cpp.o):(.eh_frame+0xbb): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEscCharsetProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEscCharSetProber::~nsEscCharSetProber()':
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x1bb): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEscCharsetProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEscCharSetProber::~nsEscCharSetProber()':
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEscCharsetProber.cpp.o):nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x1e9): more undefined references to `operator delete(void*)' follow
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEscCharsetProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEscCharSetProber::nsEscCharSetProber(unsigned int)':
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x296): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x2b6): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEscCharsetProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEscCharSetProber::~nsEscCharSetProber()':
nsEscCharsetProber.cpp:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEscCharsetProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI18nsEscCharSetProber[_ZTI18nsEscCharSetProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEscCharsetProber.cpp.o):(.eh_frame+0x137): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o): In function `nsMBCSGroupProber::nsMBCSGroupProber(unsigned int)':
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0x964): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0x97f): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0x9d0): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0x9f9): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xa22): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xa43): more undefined references to `operator new(unsigned long)' follow
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o): In function `nsMBCSGroupProber::nsMBCSGroupProber(unsigned int)':
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xd6b): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xda5): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o): In function `nsMBCSGroupProber::~nsMBCSGroupProber()':
nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0x8f0): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI17nsMBCSGroupProber[_ZTI17nsMBCSGroupProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV23JapaneseContextAnalysis[_ZTV23JapaneseContextAnalysis]+0x10): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV23JapaneseContextAnalysis[_ZTV23JapaneseContextAnalysis]+0x18): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI23JapaneseContextAnalysis[_ZTI23JapaneseContextAnalysis]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsMBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):(.eh_frame+0x67): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp.o): In function `nsSBCSGroupProber::nsSBCSGroupProber()':
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xdf4): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xe28): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xe5c): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xe90): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xec4): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xef8): more undefined references to `operator new(unsigned long)' follow
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp.o): In function `nsSBCSGroupProber::nsSBCSGroupProber()':
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0x13fb): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0x1422): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp.o): In function `nsSBCSGroupProber::~nsSBCSGroupProber()':
nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp:(.text+0xdc9): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI17nsSBCSGroupProber[_ZTI17nsSBCSGroupProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCSGroupProber.cpp.o):(.eh_frame+0x67): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCharSetProber.cpp.o): In function `nsSingleByteCharSetProber::~nsSingleByteCharSetProber()':
nsSBCharSetProber.cpp:(.text._ZN25nsSingleByteCharSetProberD0Ev[_ZN25nsSingleByteCharSetProberD0Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSBCharSetProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI25nsSingleByteCharSetProber[_ZTI25nsSingleByteCharSetProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSJISProber.cpp.o): In function `nsSJISProber::~nsSJISProber()':
nsSJISProber.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsSJISProberD2Ev[_ZN12nsSJISProberD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSJISProber.cpp.o): In function `nsSJISProber::~nsSJISProber()':
nsSJISProber.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsSJISProberD0Ev[_ZN12nsSJISProberD0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsSJISProber.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsSJISProberD0Ev[_ZN12nsSJISProberD0Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsSJISProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI12nsSJISProber[_ZTI12nsSJISProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUTF8Prober.cpp.o): In function `nsUTF8Prober::~nsUTF8Prober()':
nsUTF8Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsUTF8ProberD2Ev[_ZN12nsUTF8ProberD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUTF8Prober.cpp.o): In function `nsUTF8Prober::~nsUTF8Prober()':
nsUTF8Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsUTF8ProberD0Ev[_ZN12nsUTF8ProberD0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsUTF8Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsUTF8ProberD0Ev[_ZN12nsUTF8ProberD0Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsUTF8Prober.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI12nsUTF8Prober[_ZTI12nsUTF8Prober]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsLatin1Prober.cpp.o): In function `nsLatin1Prober::~nsLatin1Prober()':
nsLatin1Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN14nsLatin1ProberD0Ev[_ZN14nsLatin1ProberD0Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsLatin1Prober.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI14nsLatin1Prober[_ZTI14nsLatin1Prober]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(CharDistribution.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI24CharDistributionAnalysis[_ZTI24CharDistributionAnalysis]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(CharDistribution.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI25EUCTWDistributionAnalysis[_ZTI25EUCTWDistributionAnalysis]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(CharDistribution.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI25EUCKRDistributionAnalysis[_ZTI25EUCKRDistributionAnalysis]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(CharDistribution.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI26GB2312DistributionAnalysis[_ZTI26GB2312DistributionAnalysis]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(CharDistribution.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI24Big5DistributionAnalysis[_ZTI24Big5DistributionAnalysis]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(CharDistribution.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI24SJISDistributionAnalysis[_ZTI24SJISDistributionAnalysis]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(CharDistribution.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI25EUCJPDistributionAnalysis[_ZTI25EUCJPDistributionAnalysis]+0x0): more undefined references to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info' follow
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsHebrewProber.cpp.o): In function `nsHebrewProber::~nsHebrewProber()':
nsHebrewProber.cpp:(.text._ZN14nsHebrewProberD0Ev[_ZN14nsHebrewProberD0Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsHebrewProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI14nsHebrewProber[_ZTI14nsHebrewProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsBig5Prober.cpp.o): In function `nsBig5Prober::~nsBig5Prober()':
nsBig5Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsBig5ProberD2Ev[_ZN12nsBig5ProberD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsBig5Prober.cpp.o): In function `nsBig5Prober::~nsBig5Prober()':
nsBig5Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsBig5ProberD0Ev[_ZN12nsBig5ProberD0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsBig5Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN12nsBig5ProberD0Ev[_ZN12nsBig5ProberD0Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsBig5Prober.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI12nsBig5Prober[_ZTI12nsBig5Prober]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCJPProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEUCJPProber::~nsEUCJPProber()':
nsEUCJPProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCJPProberD2Ev[_ZN13nsEUCJPProberD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCJPProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEUCJPProber::~nsEUCJPProber()':
nsEUCJPProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCJPProberD0Ev[_ZN13nsEUCJPProberD0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsEUCJPProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCJPProberD0Ev[_ZN13nsEUCJPProberD0Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCJPProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI13nsEUCJPProber[_ZTI13nsEUCJPProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCKRProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEUCKRProber::~nsEUCKRProber()':
nsEUCKRProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCKRProberD2Ev[_ZN13nsEUCKRProberD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCKRProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEUCKRProber::~nsEUCKRProber()':
nsEUCKRProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCKRProberD0Ev[_ZN13nsEUCKRProberD0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsEUCKRProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCKRProberD0Ev[_ZN13nsEUCKRProberD0Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCKRProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI13nsEUCKRProber[_ZTI13nsEUCKRProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCTWProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEUCTWProber::~nsEUCTWProber()':
nsEUCTWProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCTWProberD2Ev[_ZN13nsEUCTWProberD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCTWProber.cpp.o): In function `nsEUCTWProber::~nsEUCTWProber()':
nsEUCTWProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCTWProberD0Ev[_ZN13nsEUCTWProberD0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsEUCTWProber.cpp:(.text._ZN13nsEUCTWProberD0Ev[_ZN13nsEUCTWProberD0Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsEUCTWProber.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI13nsEUCTWProber[_ZTI13nsEUCTWProber]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsGB2312Prober.cpp.o): In function `nsGB18030Prober::~nsGB18030Prober()':
nsGB2312Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN15nsGB18030ProberD2Ev[_ZN15nsGB18030ProberD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsGB2312Prober.cpp.o): In function `nsGB18030Prober::~nsGB18030Prober()':
nsGB2312Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN15nsGB18030ProberD0Ev[_ZN15nsGB18030ProberD0Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
nsGB2312Prober.cpp:(.text._ZN15nsGB18030ProberD0Ev[_ZN15nsGB18030ProberD0Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
uchardet//libuchardet.a(nsGB2312Prober.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI15nsGB18030Prober[_ZTI15nsGB18030Prober]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If make shared one and try to use it in my program, it compiles, but when I run it, I have:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libuchardet.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I compile in this way:

```
gcc test.c  -Ithird -Lthird/parserutils/lib_amd64/ -lparserutils -I uchardet/ -L uchardet/ -luchardet
```

OK! This works!

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=uchardet/ ./a.out
```

But can I use static linking here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include more error output as well as a small example of *how* you are linking it.  I'm assuming as well that you are linking this into a C program of yours ;-).

Comment: You can try something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/location/where/lubuchardet ./your_exe`. Or, `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`. The alternative is static linking, which will put the library in the executable (removing the need to mess with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.)

Comment: "What do I do in a wrong way?" - presumably you are linking with `gcc` instead of `g++`.

Comment: Yes, but it is a C bindinig. It sould be compilable with gcc, isn't it?

Comment: remyabel, your advice is helpful, but how to deal with undefined references when static linking?

Comment: @Leonidas for the `-I` and `-L` flags, try specifying the absolute path.

Comment: @remyabel, it doesn't work too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For shared library case: by default, RTLD applies only public library search paths. To add another one, add an option when linking the binary: `-Wl,-rpath=$libdir`, e.g.

```
gcc test.c  -Ithird -Lthird/parserutils/lib_amd64/ -lparserutils -I uchardet/ -L uchardet/ -luchardet -Wl,-rpath=`pwd`/uchardet
```

This option will ask RTLD to search libraries also in the specified directory. It can be specified multiple times for each additional directory invoked here.

What is having happened for the static library case, you can determine using `ldd` for the shared library. Most likely it requires libg++, libstdc++ or analog, depending on your system. If so, you should add its static analog also for your linking. `g++` does this automatically even if pure C code is compiled, but `gcc` doesn't.

Comment: D'oh, I use `gcc` instead of `g++` again.